# react-native-svg: cannot create svg from xml

Tags: reactjs, react-native, svg, react-native-svg

Hi I was trying to generate an svg on react-native app with react-native-svg, as per the docs I used SvgXml to generate svg from xml but it was not working. Here is the svg component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SvgXml } from 'react-native-svg';

const xml =
  "<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='800' height='800' viewBox='0 0 200 200'><rect fill='#ffffff' width='200' height='200'/><defs><linearGradient id='a' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='88' y1='88' x2='0' y2='0'><stop offset='0' stop-color='#1a7677'/><stop offset='1' stop-color='#2abbbe'/></linearGradient><linearGradient id='b' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x1='75' y1='76' x2='168' y2='160'><stop offset='0' stop-color='#258f7a'/><stop offset='0.09' stop-color='#2eb398'/><stop offset='0.18' stop-color='#34c9ab'/><stop offset='0.31' stop-color='#39dbbb'/><stop offset='0.44' stop-color='#3ce8c5'/><stop offset='0.59' stop-color='#3ff2ce'/><stop offset='0.75' stop-color='#41fad5'/><stop offset='1' stop-color='#42ffd9'/></linearGradient><filter id='c' x='0' y='0' width='200%' height='200%'><feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='12' /></filter></defs><polygon fill='url(#a)' points='0 174 0 0 174 0'/><path fill='#000' fill-opacity='.5' filter='url(#c)' d='M121.8 174C59.2 153.1 0 174 0 174s63.5-73.8 87-94c24.4-20.9 87-80 87-80S107.9 104.4 121.8 174z'/><path fill='url(#b)' d='M142.7 142.7C59.2 142.7 0 174 0 174s42-66.3 74.9-99.3S174 0 174 0S142.7 62.6 142.7 142.7z'/></svg>";

export default function PageTurner() {
  return <SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />;
}
```

And here is my app component where I was importing the svg:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, FlatList } from 'react-native';

import HistoryProps from '../../fixtures/History';
import PageTurner from '../../assets/PageTurner';
import CardView from './CardView';

const History = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <PageTurner />
      <FlatList data={HistoryProps} renderItem={CardView} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default History;
```

On render I am getting this error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```